# How to get current country of Device in React Native (iOS and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-device-info

I am trying to get current country of device in but didn't find anything. Is there something to do so in React Native?
I tried using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) but it is also not supporting but in previous version it can be get by getDeviceCountry(). Now for the latest version it is showing error:

> TypeError: _reactNativeDeviceInfo.default.getDeviceCountry is not a
>   function. (In '_reactNativeDeviceInfo.default.getDeviceCountry()',
>   '_reactNativeDeviceInfo.default.getDeviceCountry' is undefined)

Comment: Can you add a code sample?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the documentation of [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) for latest version, they have moved some of their apis to [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) to reduce duplication in the react-native-community modules. [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) worked perfectly for me.

Setup:

```
$ npm install --save react-native-localize
# --- or ---
$ yarn add react-native-localize
```

Usage:

```
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

console.log(RNLocalize.getLocales());
console.log(RNLocalize.getCurrencies());
console.log(RNLocalize.getCountry());
console.log(RNLocalize.getCalendar());
console.log(RNLocalize.getTemperatureUnit());
console.log(RNLocalize.getTimeZone());
console.log(RNLocalize.uses24HourClock());
```

and many more. For detailed description please visit their official documentation by the given link: [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, maybe due to https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize/issues/81.

However, `Expo` has something from its ecosystem, which worked out perfectly:

1. `expo install expo-localization`
2. `import { getLocales } from 'expo-localization';`
3. `console.log(getLocales()[0].regionCode);`

**Edit:** docs here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/#localizationregion

Answer (score 1):

Its solved my problem;

**BREAKING CHANGE:** remove is24Hour, getTimezone, isAutoTimeZone and isAutoDateAndTime, getDeviceLocale, getDeviceCountry, getPreferredLocales

This was the result of a survey. It removes API duplication in the react-native-community modules

**Related PR**: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize/pull/65

Use `yarn add`

https://github.com/mikehardy/react-native-localize.git#e062f0d2dc3171dc18fdb7b7139d347ad03933dc to maintain
isAutoTimeZone + isAutoDateAndTime until merged

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug in the React Native. Please check their [Troubleshooting section](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/blob/290ad0163a97b5eab8d4011f4721956d229c993d/README.md#troubleshooting)

Here is what they advice:

> Seems to be a bug caused by react-native link. You can manually delete
>   libRNDeviceInfo-tvOS.a in Xcode -> [Your iOS build target] -> Build
>   Phrases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this package to get device country . to has different type of configs.

[react-native-device-country](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-country)

Some Examples

```
import DeviceCountry, {
  TYPE_ANY,
  TYPE_TELEPHONY,
  TYPE_CONFIGURATION,
} from 'react-native-device-country';

DeviceCountry.getCountryCode()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // {"code": "BY", "type": "telephony"}
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });


DeviceCountry.getCountryCode(TYPE_TELEPHONY)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // {"code": "BY", "type": "telephony"}
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });


DeviceCountry.getCountryCode(TYPE_CONFIGURATION)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // {"code": "BY", "type": "config"}
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```